# Build Table from Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to JavaScript over the past two weeks and am attempting to build a table from a button click.  Using react-bootstrap/Button and react-bootstrap-table-next libraries.  I have three files that I'm working on:

1. File that holds the layout of the page
2. A ReactButton class
3. Table class

I can render the button on the page, but can't get the table to render on a click.  On the layout page, I'm building the button with:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactButton
          name="Reset Table"
          onClick={this.buttonClick}
          keyField={{keyField: 'keyField'}}
          products={DataPopulation.sampleData()}
          columns={DataPopulation.getFields()}
          selectRowProp={{mode: 'checkbox'}}
          />
    </div>
```

The button code is:

```
class ReactButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };

    this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
  }

  async buttonClick() {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true
    });
    console.log(this.props);

    console.log("Button part")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        size="lg"
        onClick={this.buttonClick}>
        {this.props.name}
      </Button>
    )
  }
}

export default ReactButton;
```

When I click the button, I can see the log of the properties (keyField, products, columns, etc) passed to the Button class.  Is it possible to then pass these properties to a table class file and have it render the table?  Table code with the react-bootstrap-table-next libraries would be something like this, I would imagine:

```
class MultiSelectTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

...

<BootstrapTable
      keyField= { this.props.keyField }
      data={ this.props.products }
      columns={ this.props.columns }
      selectRow={ this.props.selectRowProp }
      />
```

But I'm unsure how the flow should be to call this from the main layout page.  Should I call the table build from the Button class?  And how would I render the table?

Edit: Currently reviewing [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component) for more info about it.  It seems like the logic needs to be: the page renders the button, which when clicked renders the table.  What is the preferred best practice for referencing and building hierarchical components?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the parent component:

```
buttonClick(clicked) {
 this.setState({
  buttonClicked: clicked
 })
}

render() {
    return (
     <>
      <ReactButton
       name="Reset Table"
       onClick={this.buttonClick}
       keyField={{keyField: 'keyField'}}
       products={DataPopulation.sampleData()}
       columns={DataPopulation.getFields()}
       selectRowProp={{mode: 'checkbox'}}
      />
      {this.state.buttonClicked ? <MultiSelectTable {...props} /> : null}
     </>
    )
 }
```

And then in the button component you pass the click state back to the parent components click function:

```
 buttonClick() {
   this.props.onClick(true);
 }
```

That way you make sure the table is rendered only when the button is clicked and all the props gets passed to the table component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I get "Cannot read property 'buttonClicked' of null" on line 24 of the parent component, which points to <ReactButton in the render.  Does buttonClicked need to exist in the Button class?

Comment: Have you added the buttonClick function to the constructor in the button component and binded it with 'this' ?

this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);